# echo json_encode with 2 variables with jquery form plugin

Tags: php, jquery, forms, json

code inside php file:

```
$variable1 = array( 'variable1' => "$variable1" );
      $variable2 = array( 'variable2' => "$variable2" );
            echo json_encode ($variable1);
```

code inside main page:

```
<span id="variable1"></span>
<span id="variable2"></span>
```

I am trying to make it so it echos both variables in their spans.
doing 2 echos does not work, but the single as coded above works

using the jquery form plugin for this.

Comment: I do not understand at all what the issue is.  Where does `variable1` come from? Where is this actually output?

Comment: variable 1 and 2 come from a form jumpmenu

Comment: @Pekka - It sounds like Jamie is using a PHP page to output JSON and fetching that JSON from another page using jQuery / AJAX.

Comment: @Jamie - Does my solution work for you?

Comment: @Peter Ajtai - with your edit it made it clearer for me and i managed to get it working! thankyou

Comment: Note that `"$var"` will cast the variable to string.

Comment: Nice to hear. You're welcome ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the PHP is fetched w AJAX, then you must create one JSON object with both variables:

```
<?php
    // The PHP page

    $variable = array( 'variable1' => "$variable1", 
                       'variable2' => "$variable2" );

    // One JSON for both variables
    echo json_encode($variable);
?>
```

And then on the main page, you can access the JSON object and display data from it inside your spans. You can do this as I illustrate, but however you do it, if you put the returned JSON in `data` then you can access the 2 variables with `data.variable1` and `data.variable2`.... like this:

```
$.getJSON('yourPath/yourPage.php', function(data) {

    // Inside your success callback:

    $("#variable1").html(data.variable1);
    $("#variable2").html(data.variable2);

});
```

---

Of course, if you're on the same page, you can use pure PHP:

```
<?php
    $variable = array( 'variable1' => "$variable1",
                       'variable2' => "$variable2" );
?>

...

<span id="variable1"><?php echo $variable["variable1"]; ?></span>
<span id="variable2"><?php echo $variable["variable2"]; ?></span>
```